# Contact Form: Unable to set country and province programmatically

Tags: contacts, extension, addresses

From an extension I'm trying to insert data from the geocoding of Google maps into the address form.
No problem with text fields, while I can't set the 2 SELECT fields.

In practice, in the following code:

> ```
>   CRM.$("#address_"+ contactPos +"_street_address").val(indirizzo);
>   CRM.$("#address_"+ contactPos +"_city").val(localita);
>   CRM.$("#address_"+ contactPos +"_postal_code").val(cap);
>   CRM.$("#address_"+ contactPos +"_country_id").val(paese); // Problem 1 here
>   //CRM.$("#address_"+ contactPos +"_country_id").selectmenu("refresh", true);  // If uncommented return an error
>   CRM.$("#address_"+ contactPos +"_state_province_id").val(provincia); // Problem 2 here
> ```

street_address, city and postal code are set correctly in the form, while for the remaining 2 fields (they are SELECT):

1) the country is correctly set but is not visible in the form (the previous item remains selected) but if I save the contact, I get the correct value

2) the province is not set in the form nor, after saving, in the DB

**UPDATE**

I solved the first problem by adding the following lines

> ```
>   countryDesc = CRM.$("#address_"+ contactPos +"_country_id option:selected" ).text();
>   CRM.$("#select2-chosen-"+ contactPos +"0").html(countryDesc);
> ```

The update of the province, which depends on the selected country, now works with some limitations

> ```
>   CRM.$.when(CRM.$("#address_"+ contactPos +"_country_id").trigger('change'))
>       .then (function() {
>         CRM.$("#address_"+ contactPos +"_state_province_id").val(provincia);
>         CRM.$("#select2-chosen-"+ contactPos +"1").html(desProvincia);
>         alert({/literal}" {ts escape='js'}Address updated{/ts}"{literal}+'\n'+status);
>     });
> ```

which are the following:

1) I had to put an alert ();

2) when updating an existing address, if I change the country, the province is not saved

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: just a though - do you have all the Provinces for all the countries enabled via Localisation

Comment: @petednz. perhaps because of my English but I don't understand your comment

Comment: sure. let me try again. in civi back end you can set which Countries and which Provinces are enabled. I wondered if you might be hitting a problem if you didn't have the Provinces all enabled. > Admin > Localise > Languages or /civicrm/admin/setting/localization?reset=1